# OpenRefine toDate() conversion fail

Tags: date, data-conversion, openrefine

I have a sensor log file with dates in the form `Mon Nov 30 18:21:40 UTC 2020` that I'd like to convert to OpenRefine dates.

Per [GREL Date Functions](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-Date-Functions), I thought the correct transformation would be `value.toDate('E M d H:m:s z y')`, but I consistently get "Error: Unable to convert to a date".

I've tried simple things like replacing `UTC` with `GMT`, without success.

What clue am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

That's a weird date format. I'm not sure why a sensor log wouldn't just use ISO 8601.

Try using `value.toDate('EEE MMM d H:m:s Z y')`.

It's not super obvious from the docs that you need multiple characters, but if you look at the examples at the bottom of this page, you can see them used there.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I batch-edited the data to be more acceptable, so I could get past this. Will try this approach next time.

Comment: Glad you were able to find a solution. If you find my answer useful, you can upvote and accept it.

Comment: Turns out I didn't need the batch edit: I kept the 'bad' data and moved on to data analysis using JupyterLab and Pandas.  As my data contained multiple different time formats, I used `pd.to_datetime()` with `infer_datetime_format=True`, and all were automagically converted.